# Why does conditional rendering of function components in react break my positioning css?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm make a website for a project in which I have a vertical navbar next to the main content of the page. I used bootstrap to make two main columns, one for the navbar and one for the rest of the content which is displayed using routing. I gave the column for the navbar the "fixed-top" class, which (at first) correctly made it so that the navbar stays in the same spot of the viewport regardless to where I've scrolled to on the page.

The navbar now, however, contains buttons directing to either the login page or their profile (depending on whether or not they are logged in).

In order to try to implement this I tried using conditional rendering in my navbar function component. I used an if-else statement to either render the entire navbar with the sign in button or the profile and logout buttons based on whether or not the user is signed in, however, in doing so the navbar no longer is fixed in the viewport and is instead scrolled away alongside the rest of the page.

Is it my implementation that is causing the problem? Or is this an issue inherent to conditional rendering? How would I go about fixing this?

Basic example of my app functional component

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <Container fluid>
                    <Col className="fixed-top">
                        <Navbar />
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <Routes>
                           All of my routing
                        </Routes>
                    </Col>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Basic example of my navbar functional component

```
const Navbar = () => {
    A bunch of firebase related stuff to check if the user is logged in
    const auth = getAuth();
    
    const [status, setStatus] = useState({
        status: "signed out"
    })

    useEffect(()=>{
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
              setStatus({
                status: "signed in"
              });
            } else {
              setStatus({
                status: "signed out"
              });
            }
          });
    }, [])

    if(status.status == "signed out") {
        return (
            <Card>
                Here goes all the stuff in my navbar including the website title and logo
               <ButtonGroup vertical>
                    Here are all the buttons on my navbar including the sign in page button but not 
                    including the your profile page button or logout button
               </ButtonGroup>
            </Card>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Card>
                Here goes all the stuff in my navbar including the website title and logo
               <ButtonGroup vertical>
                    Here are all the buttons on my navbar not including the sign in page button but 
                    including the your profile page button or logout button
               </ButtonGroup>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

I tried a few other methods for conditional rendering but none of them seemed to work. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`const auth = getAuth();` should be outside of the `NavBar` component.